# No response when using commandline to execute NODE.js script

Tags: node.js, http, console, request, response

I am trying to do a script where the user would access the local website and paste their encrypted text. However when I am executing the following code, no response it showing up when the user submits the text. I am trying to show the inputted text using the console.log(reqbody) however nothing shows up. Help is very appreciated thanks!

```
const http = require('http')
var qs = require("querystring");
const port = 9000

function getHome(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    response.write("<html><body>Encrypt your email! <a 
href='http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/index.html'>Click.</a> Verify 
Wi-Fi AP <a href='/send'>Click here.</a></body ></html > ")
    response.end();
}

function get404(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(404, "Resource Not Found", { "Content-Type": 
"text/html" });
    response.write("<html><title> Error 404 </title><h1>404: Resource not 
found!</h1></html >")
    response.end();
}

function get405(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", { "Content-Type": 
"text/html" });
    response.write("<html><title> Error 405</title><h1>Error 405: Method not 
supported.</h1></html >")
    response.end();
}

function getSendForm(request, response) {
    response.write("<html><body><form method='post'><form><tr><td>Enter the 
encrypted text:</td><td><input type='text' id='encryptedtext' value='Paste 
encrypted text.'/></td></tr><tr><td><input type='submit' value='Send'/></td>
</tr></form> </body></html>")  
    };

    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        console.log(request.url);
        switch (request.method) {
            case "GET":
                if (request.url === "/") {
                    getHome(request, response);
                }
                else if (request.url === "/send") {
                    getSendForm(request, response);
                }
                else {
                    get404(request, response);
                }
                break;
            case "POST":
                if (request.url === "/send") {
                    var reqBody = '';
                    request.on('data', function (data) {
                        reqBody += data;
                        if (reqBody.length > 1e7) //10mb
                        {
                            response.writeHead(413, 'Too large encrypted 
data.', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                            response.write("<html><title> Error 413 </title>
<h1>413: Too much data.</h1></html >")
                            response.end();
                        }
                    });
                    request.on('end', function (data) {
                        console.log(reqBody);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    get404(request, response);
                }
                break;
           default:
                get405(request, response);
                break;
        }
    }).listen(port);
    console.log("server")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. In function `getSendForm()`, `response.end()` is missing, which means the webpage `/send` will never end loading -- there would be a spinner keep running in the page tab.
2. Incorrectly inserted `<form>` tag, as @TonyY mentioned.
3. The `action` of form is missing, which should be `/send` according to your code.
4. `name` of `input` element is missing, as @TonyY mentioned.
5. `Paste encrypted text.` should be `placeholder`, not `value`.
6. `response.end()` is missing in `POST /send`'s handler, thus no response is shown to user after the form is submitted.

Here is the fixed code:

```
const http = require('http')
var qs = require("querystring");
const port = 9000

...

function getSendForm(request, response) {
  response.write("<html><body><form method='post' action='/send'><tr><td>Enter the encrypted text:</td><td><input type='text' id='encryptedtext' name='encryptedtext' placeholder='Paste encrypted text.'/></td></tr><tr><td><input type='submit' value='Send'/></td></tr></form> </body></html>")
  response.end();
};

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log(request.url);
  switch (request.method) {
    case "GET":
      if (request.url === "/") {
        getHome(request, response);
      }
      else if (request.url === "/send") {
        getSendForm(request, response);
      }
      else {
        get404(request, response);
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      if (request.url === "/send") {
        var reqBody = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
          reqBody += data;
          if (reqBody.length > 1e7) //10mb
          {
            response.writeHead(413, 'Too large encrypted data.', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            response.write("<html><title> Error 413 </title> <h1>413: Too much data.</h1></html >")
            response.end();
          }
        });
        request.on('end', function (data) {
          console.log(reqBody);
          response.end('Done!');
        });
      }
      else {
        get404(request, response);
      }
      break;
    default:
      get405(request, response);
      break;
  }
}).listen(port);
console.log("server")
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked perfectly! I will use it with the python script I created and it should work flawlessly!

Comment: I have another problem xD. Inputting !, +, -, = is outputting different text as a response on the webserver. Example entering: test! is outputting test%21 Can you help please? Thanks.

Comment: @user3108169 you can use `decodeURI()` to get the real string characters. For example, `decodeURI('%21')` in node.js will return `'!'`

Comment: Thx however decodeURIComponent(data) worked better =)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code that have two wrong, which you need to fix.

First is `<form method='post'><form>` delete one tag of **form**

Second is `<input type='text' id='encryptedtext' value='Paste encrypted text.'/>` you don't need 'id' but 'name' .

There is complete fix as bellow

```
 response.write("<html><body><form method='post'><tr><td>Enter the 
encrypted text:</td><td><input type='text' name='encryptedtext' value='Paste 
encrypted text.'/></td></tr><tr><td><input type='submit' value='Send'/></td>
</tr></form> </body></html>")  
    };
```

Comment: If my answer is useful to you,click the checkbox to accept it as the answer that help everyone can quickly find :>